# Exception: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm a beginner with C#, when I execute the code, this error message occurs:

> "An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'b'"

My code:

```
public void populateIngredients()
{
    string query = "select a.Name from Ingredients a" +
                   "inner join RecipeIngredient b ON a.Id = b.IngredientID" +
                   "where b.RecipeID = @RecipeID";

    using (con = new SqlConnection(connection))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con))
    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecipeID", listRecipes.SelectedValue);

        DataTable IngredientTable = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(IngredientTable);    // The error points here     

        listIngredients.DisplayMember = "Name";
        listIngredients.ValueMember = "Id";
        listIngredients.DataSource = IngredientTable;
    }
}
```

My database has three tables:

1. `Recipe` (Id, Name, PrepTime, Instructions)
2. `Ingredients` (Id, Name)
3. `RecipeIngredient` (Id, RecipeID, IngredientID)

Comment: Missing a space between _from Ingredients a_ and the following _inner join_ the same before the _where_

Answer (score 0):

a space between some words is missing!
put a space " " first of each string constants.
your string query is like this now:
        `"select a.Name from Ingredients ainner join RecipeIngredient b ON a.Id = b.IngredientID" +`

and there is not any spaces between `a` and `inner` words.